# zener diodes, different voltages, and using a relay to control its opperation....will this work?

Tags: relay, potentiometer, zener, solenoid-valve

Ok so I am going to admit that I am an idiot when it comes to circuits. However, some advice would be appreciated with regard to my idea. I am trying to control two seperate circuits, each with different voltage requirements, and hoping to use two relays from one inital push to make switch...so here goes my attempt at the explaination. There is a zener diode in there also, which I need some help with because I may be placing it in the wrong position within the circuit for the outcome that I require.

Background information: The aim of the project is to have two actions take place simoultaniously, with one circuit controlling them both.

Circuit one is using a reference voltage (vehicle ECU) at 5v, this is passed through a POT (throttle pedal position sensor) and then returned to the ECU (0.25-4.75v dependent on POT position). After the POT but before the ECU, there will be a 3.5v zener diode in reverse bais mode, leading to ground, so that the maximum voltage the ECU ever recieves back is 3.5v.

Circuit two is much simpler. It is 12v constant voltage, controlling a solenoid valve, with full open and full closed positions.

Control circuit would be a push to make switch with 12v, the pushing of which button would allow the 12v to pass through to two relays, one of which completing the circuit with the solenoid valve, the other breaking the zener effect on the ECU circuit, and allowing the ECU to recieve more than 3.5v if the POT allows this.

I hope I have explained this enough so as you can understand.

I did have another idea, where the push to make switch would control the initial 3.5v zener only, and then have another 4.5v zener further down the line, so that this 4.5v zener leaked off the voltage to a relay which completed the circuit for the solenoid. This would then only open the solenoid valve when two requirements were met, one being if 4.5v or more was output from the POT, and the other being the push to make switch was activated.

I could be talking complete gibberish, but it kind of makes sence in my head lol

.
.
.

EDIT

OK so here is what I have come up with, given your helpful inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhp03h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, when the push to break switch is pressed, the voltage the voltage sensor receives is not limited, when the push to break switch is not pressed, the maximum voltage the sensor receives is 3.45v or there abouts.

My next step is to incorporate the solenoid activation in to this some how, so that either:-

A) solenoid is activated when voltage is above 3.45v at the sensor (this would mean the push to break switch must have been pressed)
B) much simpler i think, simply using a double pole ( on/on ) switch so that the solenoid is activated, or the zener is activated, never both

I have cracked it!!! 
PLEASE READ CAREFULLY BEFORE ANY ATTEMPT TO TEST!

There are two variable resistors, both of them (R1 & R2) are connected to the same sensor on the throttle pedal. This is to ensure the ECU can tell if one is faulty, by having voltage linearization between the two, one raising the voltage, one reducing it. Whatever happens to one POT must also happen to the other. SW1 is a push to break switch. The solenoid valve will be wired in after the lamp, I could not find a solenoid sign so I thought why not incorporate a lamp to indicate when this was activated, and also for the purposes of the simulation.

If anyone finds any faults with it, I would be more than grateful if you could bring these to my attention.
Thank you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWX78W.png)</sup>

Comment: It would be immeasurably better if, instead of telling us how you propose to get to where you want to go, you just told us your destination.  An analogy would be that if you found yourself at the  airport of a strange city and needed to get a particular hotel, wandering outside you'd hire a cab and then, instead of telling the driver where you wanted to go, you told him how you thought he should go to get you there.

Comment: origin is button not pressed, solenoid valve closed, ecu gets max 3.5v.....destination is button pressed, solenoid valve open, ecu gets max output of the POT

Comment: Just realised for the second idea i had as a solution, i could just use a push to break switch to control the 3.5v zener

Comment: Just summarize and not create a novel dude.

Comment: To summarise, I don't know how to summarise it lol

Comment: here is my attempt at summarising it. I have 5v reference going into a POT, the POT outputs 0.25-4.75v, this is then sent to a voltage sensor. I want to limit the voltage the sensor recieves to 3.5v, but remove this with the push of a button when required, then reactivated when the button is no longer pressed. I also want the button to open a solenoid valve at the same time.

Comment: The 1N4733 is a 5.1 volt Zener diode, so it won't be doing any clamping.  Matter of fact, it might as well not even be there. Same goes for the one ohm resistor and the switch. The way it stands right now, the pot might as well be tied directly to the 5 volt supply.

Comment: please note the 2v...i have edited the voltage in the properties on the simulator.

Comment: What you're using to make your drawings can also be used to simulate the circuit.  Why not give it a try?  In particular, take a look at the current through R5 and the Zener.

Comment: This is what I did, but i keep meeting dead ends. I noticed that the zener causes the resistor R5 to drop 2v across it. However my concern is that I am an electronics novice, and it took me about 3 days just to get to here, am I going to overheat something? Is there another way of doing this, but after the POT?

Comment: I don't mean to be unkind, but instead of all this piecemeal time wasting mucking about,  why don't you just just state what you want this thing to do, in the end?

Comment: I am attempting to add a "push to pass" button to a motor vehicle

Comment: isn't current irrelevant as the voltage sensor doesn't read current

Comment: If there's 2 volts being dropped across the Zener, then there'll be 3 volts dropped across the 1 ohm resistor and then, by Ohm's law, the current through both the resistor and the Zener will be be $$  I = \frac{E}{R} = \frac {3V}{1\Omega} = 3 \text{ amperes}$$ Since there's 2 volts being dropped across the Zener with 3 amperes through it, then the power it'll dissipate will be $$ P = IE = 3A \times 2V = 6 \text { watts}$$ that package is rated for 1 watt, but what's even worse is that **there is no 2 volt 1N4733**

Comment: from the simulator, there was 5v before the 1ohm resistor, and 3.459 or something after the resistor, this is why I am asking the questions as it doesn't make sense....there was 3.459v before the zener, and zero after the zener but before ground.

do 2v zeners exist?
Also i have no idea of the part numbers, i just used the provided zener in the simulator and changed the voltage to see if it were possible

Comment: Sorry, but I have no clue.

Comment: OK, what's a "push to pass" button supposed to make the motor vehicle do?

Comment: It is a feature which gives the motor vehicle's engine a boost in power to overtake another vehicle safely. Modifications are made to the HEX file within the ECU so that when a certain voltage is measured at the sensor, it gives an extreme boost in power. The ECU uses the voltage from the POT (drivers accelerator pedal) and cross references this with values in the HEX file to determine how much power the engine should make. By editing the HEX file, and controlling the voltage from the POT, at the push of a button you can allow extra voltage (thus more engine power).

Comment: So if you floor it, the most you can get out of the pot is 3.5 volts into the sensor, but if you push the button while it's floored, you'll get 4.75 volts out?

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly the thing i require to happen.....but it needs to be linear, so when you get to between say 80% & 100% pedal travel with it limited to 3.5v max, there isn't a dead spot

Comment: This whole thing sounds like a lot of dangerous bullshit to me, since if you want to pass someone you have to  floor the gas pedal and then take one hand off the wheel to go feeling around looking for a pushbutton switch.  Why not just take, say, the last 10% of the gas pedal's travel to kick in the \$N\_2O\$ or whatever you're using for the boost and be done with it?

Comment: People didn't go to the moon because it was safe, they did it because they wanted to, because why not? The button will be on the steering wheel, and to inject nitrous oxide you also need to add extra fuel. The extra fuel has to come from somewhere, and because this is for a compression ignition application, this fuel cannot be added into the cylinder before injection commences, as major damage will be caused. People use propane or methanol instead of diesel, but power increases are less impressive than they could be. The extra fuel that I require can be programmed in to the ECU and injected

Comment: Also I have found the solution to my issues. I just need to incorporate the solenoid control system into this circuit 

[link] (https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10489912_10153429713872144_7314268114234652433_n.jpg?oh=a060b54be2fcd4078872810a335c47a7&oe=57111042)

Answer (score 2):

From one of your comments, it seems that all you need is a DPDT (double pole, double throw) pushbutton.  One pole would be used to apply power to the solenoid valve, and the other pole would switch the voltage sensor input between the pot wiper and a 3.5 volt source.

Comment: the 3.5v is not a separate source of electricity, it is from the POT. Best way i can explain it is that i want the voltage after the POT to be limited to 3.5v max, and there to be a switch deactivating this function, so that the sensor can read the genuine voltage output of the POT and not the limited votage

Answer (score 1):

In response to your last comment (summarizing), as far as I can understand...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO5Yyp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Vpot varies from approximately 0.25V to 4.75V.

**Vz = Vpot as long as Vpot ≤ 3.5V.**

**If Vpot > 3.5V, Vz = 3.5V.**

When the switch **SW1 (DPDT) is flipped** (toggling a toggle switch / pushing a pushbutton), your **output is disconnected** and set low (0V), and your **circuit for your solenoid valve is completed** (separate from this circuit -- just mechanically connected so they happen at the same time thanks to the switch mechanics).

*The only problem I can think of with this circuit is Zener activation current, so you might have to play with these resistor values to get enough current to flow through the Zener Diode at all values of Vpot.*

Comment: You could also just bias the pot with extra resistors to make Vpot (max) = 3.5V and Vpot (min) = 0.25V.

Comment: I think i realise where i've been going wrong, i've been assuming electricity flows from - to + rather than + to - lol. Yes this is fantastic, thanks. This is what i needed to know. The value at Vz is = to value at Vpot unless Vpot reaches above 3.5v, at which point Vz always = 3.5v. To deactivate this function, could a push to break switch be used after the zener but before ground?

Comment: this would work, but i wish to be able to turn off the 3.5v limit when requested.

Comment: Just ran a simulation and it works just as I would want, the important part seems to be the 1k resistor after the pot. I assume that using the resistor brings the zener into some sort of operating window?

Answer (score 1):

Your descriptions are very confusing, but I think this will get you where you want to go:

V1 is your 12 volt source, which is used to supply power to L1, your solenoid, and the 78L05, which is a 5 volt series regulator used to convert 12 volts to 5 volts for your pot, comprising R1, R2, and R3, R1 and R3 setting the high and low voltage limits for R2's output. D1 is a catch diode used to protect S1A by  clamping the solenoid's turnoff spike to about 13 volts.

S1 is a double pole double throw momentary switch, with S1A being the normally open contacts of one section of the switch, and S1B being the normally closed contacts of the other section.

S1B is used to connect D2 to R2's output, which will allow R2's output to rise to no more than 3.5 volts when S1 isn't being pressed.

When it is, however, S1A will be made, energizing the solenoid, and S1B will be opened, which will allow R2's output voltage to appear, unclamped, at the the input of the voltage sensor.

As an aside, D2 is merely representative of an actual clamp, which could be made from, say, an LM385 or the like.

[image]

Comment: Please, I haven't got a clue what is going on here.

Comment: @JamesShillShillinglaw: Just to allay confusion in the future,  I edited out the question in my answer about if you wanted a circuit description,  and added the circuit description since you said you wanted one. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will read this in a second. I have made a slight amendment to my original question at the top, please have a look and see if the circuit I have shown makes some kind of sense to you, and would it work to give the desired effect.

Comment: That seems as though it would work, but the 12v and 5v inputs are seperate. the 12v is purely to operate the solenoid, the 5v purely to provide reference for the sensor after the pot

Comment: Did you not read/understand the circuit description you asked for?

Comment: yes i understand that you have used the 12v source and stepped the voltage down to 5v....however as explained in the original post, the 5v is supplied by the ECU and the 12v source is a separate entity. I have the solution to the POT section of the circuit now anyway

Comment: @JamesShillShillinglaw: If the 5 volt source is the ECU  and the 12 volt source is the battery,  it should be easy to just eliminate the 78L05  since it won't be needed. In any case, I think congratulations are in order since you managed to figure everything out all by yourself,  with no help from any of us, which must be the reason you haven't accepted any answer or, at the very least, upvoted answers which were helpful. BTW, how about if you post your scheme for clamping the TPS's output to 3.5 volts, please?

Comment: I did, @sean mann helped greatly with his post below, as the way the zener has to be wired in and the resistor in front of it. Also I said in my post "OK so here is what I have come up with, given your helpful inputs." lol. I'm not sure what you mean by upvoted as well. I have completely finished the whole circuit setup as well, which I am going to prototype this week, and I will post the results here. 
I will post a link to the schematic now as well.

Comment: <!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

![schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WX78W.png)

<!-- End schematic -->

Comment: Also I have made amendments to the original post so people can test etc

Comment: In the schematic at your link, you've got a couple of 10 ohm pots with 5 volts across each of them, which means that each pot will dissipate 2.5 watts. Good luck with sourcing that on the cheap, and can the 5 volt output from your ECU supply 1 ampere to feed those hungry pots?  Then, you have  1000 ohms in series with each of the Zeners, which means that even with the pots cranked, the highest current you'll be able to push through the Zeners will be 5 milliamperes, a far cry from their test current which, when passed through them, will guarantee their specified output voltage.

Comment: They're 100 ohm, and their resistance is irrelevant anyway because this is just a prototype to be used as a skeleton, which can be built on and used for a whole host of different applications. The theory is all I needed to establish. I won't bother explaining the mechanics or hexidecimal programming side of things as it is not essential to know in terms of "is it going to work." I now know it can work, and I know how to make it work. The POT's are already built into the vehicles fly by wire system, I will simply intercept this signal. I can now program it through ladder logic and go from there