# Is this something a P.L.C. would be able to do?

Tags: mosfet, potentiometer, zener, comparator, plc

I wish to replace the zener diodes with a programmable chip, so that I can program the chip to do exactly what the zener diodes do in this circuit. This will then make the circuit universal to all my applications, and all I would need to do is reprogram the chip to use it on an application that requires different voltage limitations. In this circuit (if you need to simulate it and play with the POT's and the push to make switch to understand it, do so) they are voltage limiters, limiting either the minimum voltage d2, or limiting the maximum voltage d1 & d6.

Please read this carefully before testing. POT's R1 & R2 are attached to the same wiper, so what happens to one must happen to the other. The switch SW1 is a push to break switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbMkwp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: yeah if the pic-axe includes DAC it could probably be used.

Comment: I read something on the PICAXE that mentioned DAC or something like that. I will quickly check now. What is DAC & what does it do?

Comment: This question is as bad as the [previous one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/207798/zener-diodes-different-voltages-and-using-a-relay-to-control-its-opperation) but at least it's shorter. Why not explain, in brief, what the circuit is for, what the inputs are and what the desired output is? Then follow that with the question - e.g., how much of this could be carried out with a micro? We'd love to help but with such a jumbled posting you make it very difficult. The schematic helps but has to be read right to left to follow inputs to outputs.

Comment: A [PLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) is a high-reliability programmable device used in industrial automation. PICAXE seems to be a microcontroller originally designed for educational users, and it is not a PLC. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: I thought a PLC and microcontroller were the same thing. I'm not very good with electronics hence the poor descriptions. I guess we could talk about which one would be best suited for the job. Which would you say would be the best given the task I require it to do?

Comment: @transistor although your inputs are appreciated, I would also appreciate if you took some time to understand that I have never created an electronic circuit before in my life, other than attaching a bulb to a battery in junior school, and thus I may not be able to explain the theory very well. The previous question actually described what I have come up with very well if you read it back, and look at the final circuit I have come up with. I sort of knew what needed to happen, but I just didn't know how to implement it into an actual circuit.

Comment: I will edit the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in-fact you could probably simulate the whole circuit in software 
and drive the two meters with PWM signals from the pic.

Comment: The only things I can replace with the P.L.C. are the zener diodes, the comparator, & possibly the MOSFET. The POT's have to be physical as they are attached to a physical lever

Comment: yes, connect the pots between vcc and ground and read them  using the ADC in the PICAXE, sense the switch setting, and then do the rest in software, create PWM signals to drive the meters. and a logic signal to drive the mosfet

Comment: Thank you for your help. So in essence I intercept the signal between the POT and volt meters, ADC to change it to a signal the PICAXE can manipulate, then program the PICAXE to modify the signal it receives, which then sends this through a DAC to turn it back into a voltage?
Would something like this be a logical program to give it, but obviously wrote in the correct program code.

If sw1 closed, vm1 = r1 unless r1> 3.5v(or whatever zener voltage i would have used)
If sw1 open, vm1 = r1
Similar sort of thing for the r2 side as well but obviously backwards as the POT is backwards?

Comment: yeah, that sounds about right.  do tests on a mock-up if getting it wrong will be expensive

Comment: yeah i thought about using a breadboard and making a prototype, I will have to look into the DAC and ADC in a bit more detail before carrying out any experiments. Do you know of any programmable chips that have DAC and ADC functions built in to them, as from what I read on the PICAXE there is no mention of ADC, or would they just call this a PWM output signal? something I did see was 0-255, I am guessing this means there are 256 different variations in signal (voltage in my case) that can be created as an output to send in my case to VM1 and VM3?